# HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() hangs randomly

Tags: c#, http

I have the following code :

```
public static QHttpResponse Execute(QHttpRequest request)
{
    //Setup the request
    HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(request.GetFinalUrl());
    webrequest.AllowAutoRedirect = request.IsAllowRedirects;
    webrequest.Method = request.Method;
    webrequest.Accept = "application/json, text/javascript;q=0.9, */*;q=0.5";
    webrequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
    //request.Host is set automatically
    webrequest.UserAgent = request.UserAgent;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Referrer))
        webrequest.Referer = request.Referrer;
    webrequest.Timeout = 50000;
    webrequest.KeepAlive = false;
    webrequest.CachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.Revalidate);
    webrequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
    if (request.IsAjax)
    {
        webrequest.Headers.Add("X-Request", "JSON");
        webrequest.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        webrequest.Headers.Add("X-Prototype-Version", "1.7");
    }

    // Cookies
    webrequest.CookieContainer = request.Cookies;

    // Write the data to the body for POST and other methods
    if (request.IsMethodPost())
    {
        byte[] dataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request.GetDataParamString());
        webrequest.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length;

        using (Stream requestStream = webrequest.GetRequestStream())
            requestStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
    }

    // Get the response
    HttpWebResponse webresponse;
    try
    {
        webresponse = webrequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    }
    catch (WebException wex)
    {
        if(request.IsBypassError)
            webresponse = wex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
        else
            throw;
    }

    // Read to QHttpResponse object
    QHttpResponse response = new QHttpResponse();
    response.StatusCode = webresponse.StatusCode;
    response.NewCookies = webresponse.Cookies;
    using (Stream responseStream = webresponse.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            response.Reply = reader.ReadToEnd();

    webresponse.Close();

    return response;
}
```

I have this code run multiple times from various locations and randomly (Every couple of hours), it hangs at this line :

```
webresponse = webrequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

I tried setting `webrequest.KeepAlive = false;`, but I continued to receive the error.

I'd like any available help on solving this, thanks in advance.

**EDIT** : I'd like to add that this code is executed from two threads. Occasionally they may connect to the same host, but only from these 2 threads. Also, as I see, the response is closed appropriately.

**EDIT 2** : Visual studio's debugger says the execution is really stuck at `System.dll!System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive`.

**EDIT 3** : In an attempt to see exactly what was causing the bug, I modified the "Get the response" code from above to

```
// Get the response
HttpWebResponse webresponse = null;
try
{
    webresponse = webrequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
}
catch (WebException wex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Time : " + DateTime.Now);
    Console.WriteLine("Thread name : " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Exception : " + wex);
    Console.WriteLine("Exc msg : " + wex.Message);
    Console.WriteLine("Url : " + request.GetFinalUrl());

    if (request.IsBypassError)
        webresponse = wex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
    else
    {
        if (webresponse != null)
        {
            webresponse.Close();
            webresponse.Dispose();
        }

        throw;
    }
}
```

I received this output :

```
Time : 5/11/2015 3:13:35 AM 
Thread name : BOT A
Exception : System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at Gameloop.Util.Web.QWebClient.Execute(QHttpRequest request) in e:\Visual Studio - Workspace\Gameloop.Util\Gameloop.Util\Web\QWebClient.cs:line 52 
Exc msg : The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. 
Url : https://website1.com/url/path/to/something (I changed this)
```

This was the only displayed error and was encountered by thread "BOT A". However, this was not the url the threads appear to have actually frozen at. "BOT A" was actually frozen at 12:00pm at website2.com and "BOT B" was actually frozen at 7:00am at website3.com. I doubt the hanging has much to do with the exception since the requests would have been made a large number of times after that before the actual hang.

Comment: I would suggest called `webresponse.Dispose()` right after `webresponse.Close()` and then try again.

Comment: I will do so, please note it may take even days to confirm your technique (Especially if it works)

Comment: Better, put the WebResponse into a `using` block.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I would try broadening your net to capture all Exceptions, not just WebExceptions.

Answer (score 1):

My first inclination is that you may need to dispose of your `HttpWebResponse`. Normally you might wrap that in a `using` block, but since you have two places where `webresponse` might be assigned, you might just want to dispose it explicitly, like this.

```
webresponse.Close();
webresponse.Dispose();
```

I would start there.

Comment: Just received the same error again. Considering that the frequency of the error <i>seems</i> to have reduced, I would say that adding Dispose() may have helped, but it hasn't solved the problem. I have added more details to the question.

Comment: Can you see what the properties of your `HttpWebRequest ` are? It might be that one of the properties is not being set correctly.

Comment: I don't quite understand... Do you mean to say one of the HttpWebRequest properties are not being set, as in a bug in System.dll? How would I check this?

Comment: I guess it depends on how the error is manifesting. If it is throwing an exception, you could write the values to a log in the catch statement. If it truly is just hanging indefinitely, you might want to write the properties to a log before calling `GetResponse()`.

Comment: I added a statement to print the exception in the catch block. The bug occurred again a few mins ago and it seems it does throw an Exception HTTP 522. However, this does not bring up the usual "<app> has stopped working" error. I'm trying to get more details right now.

Comment: Being able to see the innermost exception message would be the most useful.

Comment: Nets are in place, I'll post back the next time it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Just add below in the try block:

```
httpWReq.Timeout = 3000;
```